# When checking whether a ModelState is valid, is there a way to return the specific error?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

When checking whether a ModelState is valid, is there a way to return the specific error?

Let's say I'm checking if there are any errors in my controller with the code below.

Controller

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest( "Invalid request");
```

My model:

```
[StringLength(500, ErrorMessage = "cant have more than 500 caracteres")]
public string Description { get; set; }
```

I want it to return the model error "cant have more than 500 caracteres", how would I go about this?.

Comment: Easiest way is to include those in the model's properties and just call "return Page();"  You can also set specific error message text there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, see [ModelState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.modelstate?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) properties.

Example:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var message = string.Join(" | ", ModelState.Values
        .SelectMany(v => v.Errors)
        .Select(e => e.ErrorMessage));
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, message);
}
```